# Validation and Learning Curve shape Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, validation

Can someone help me explain the following graph of the learning curve?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your training accuracy increases with the number of training samples, which is normal. Yet, your validation accuracy decreases with the number of training samples, meaning you would be overfitting. The odd part is that your validation accuracy is above your training accuracy : this is not normal because your model is doing better on never seen data than on training data.

Ask yourself the following questions :

- Are my training data and validation data issued from the same distribution ?
- Is my scoring function relevant ? (Most of the time, accuracy is between 0 and 1)

If your score were a loss (ie the lower the better), then it would seem like a normal curve in the learning process : your validation error would decrease and get closer to the training error. You could keep increasing the sample size to get a better validation score. The gap between your curves is pretty big indicating underfitting.